# 13.04 reboot from terminal

Tags: reboot

when I try to reboot my system from the terminal it down't work.   I type

```
sync
sudo reboot now
```

and this is supposed to write the cache to disk, the n reboot.  Instead it closes my Xwindows, and leaves me at a shell command that ends with #.

Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 2):

This is not expected behavior, and may be coming from a third-party hardware driver.

With the `reboot` command, you can try the `-p` option or the `-f` option if it is not shutting down all the way.

Also, you don't need to run `sync` before `reboot`; `reboot` will run `sync` automatically!

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt `shutdown -r now`.

Comment: To highlight code, put it in backticks (`). You can get help by clicking the orange question mark at the top right of the answer field. Also, I think you slightly mangled the command, so I've attempted to edit it.

Comment: Thanks sparhawk, and as far as the code, I believe I'm mixing it up with a command in Raspian Squeeze (Raspberry Pi).

Comment: Hm, someone else downvoted you; I'm not sure why. However, I'm pretty sure debian/raspian is also `shutdown -r`, rather than `-r shutdown`. The latter looks very strange to me.